# SchemaViolationException while creating a new janus cluster

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlin-server, janus

I am trying to create a janusgraph cluster with cassandra as backend and elastic for indexing. Getting a warning saying -

`org.janusgraph.core.SchemaViolationException: Adding this property for key [~T$SchemaName] and value [rtusername] violates a uniqueness constraint [SystemIndex#~T$SchemaName]`

followed by a error saying

```
ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Gremlin Server Error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not create/configure Authenticator null
```

Can someone please help me understand what I am missing here? What does **rtusername** actually mean here

Answer (score 1):

Things to check for the first error message:

- is an old graph with the same value for the keyspace present  (beware for the default value "janusgraph")?
- was the property key added by a different gremlin client (check by printing the schema, before adding the property key)?
- are you sure this happens during adding the property key to the schema (because this error can also happen while adding a property to a vertex of the graph)

The second error message is related to the communication between your gremlin client and the JanusGraph Server. Things to check:

- do the TinkerPop versions of the gremlin client and the JanusGraph Server match ([compatibility matrix](https://docs.janusgraph.org/changelog/#version-compatibility-matrix))?

Comment: So I am trying to create a fresh cluster. I am not using the default keyspace - janusgraph. Also my credentials file and the properties file have different keyspace name. I first want the gremlin server to run on port 8182, only then I can proceed and add properties, vertex, nodes etc.  Also the printSchema() gives no nodes/vertices/edges

Comment: You can post your issue on https://lists.lfaidata.foundation/g/janusgraph-users/topics with the steps and files attached to reproduce it. SO is not suited to interactive debugging.

Comment: So i realised that the credentials janusgraph schema is supposed to have Vertex Index Name of type Composite called -  **byUsername** . I created it manually in my case, and I was able to get rid of the warn and bring the server up. Any idea on how byUsername it gets created by itself ?

Comment: I believe the scarse JG documentation on the credentialsDb implies a reference to [docs on the credentials graph](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#credentials-dsl).  That states that the index needs to be created by hand.